# Hardware raid 10 + Linux LVM partition. Need I worry?

Tags: linux, hard-drive

Using proxmox.

Created a LVM partition.

Upon a google search I came across this.

"Also, if you use LVM across hard drives, you may lose all your data when only one drive fails."

Well RAID 10 mirrors right? So wouldn't I still be okay if a drive failed?

Comment: No form of RAID ever devised is a viable backup. The purpose of RAID is to maintain access to your data in the event of a drive failure. It's purpose is not to protect your data. For that you need backups. Without backups your data will be at risk.

Answer (score 1):

This note is referencing the fact that LVM supports functionality similar to RAID0 among other complex configurations.

If your underlying RAID10 volume is presented as one device to the operating system, and that RAID10 is the only **PV** within the volume group LVM is basically safe as long as your RAID10 volume is healthy.

If you had two physical drives, and you added both PVs to a volume group, and you build a logical volume that uses all the capacity from both physical drives, then the loss of either drive would essentially result in a loss of the volume group any logical volumes.  There is some option you can use within LVM to emulate various mirroring and striping modes from a RAID that could mitigate this, but AFAIK these configurations are pretty rare.  From what I have seen mostly people will use mdadm, or a hardware RAID, and their LVM volume group will just have a single 'device'.